Modifying a Linked List Head Node Without Pointer Dereferencing in C
void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    // Function body
}


The problem arises when I try to link the new node to the head of the linked list. Although I'm updating the obj pointer within the function to point to the new head node, it seems that the change isn't reflected in the actual linked list.
I need guidance on how to correctly update the head node of the linked list within the constraints of the function structure provided by LeetCode, without resorting to pointer dereferencing.
Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.
This my code, please only focus on myLinkedListAddAtHead function while using this spesific taste cases.
I've included some printf statements within the function to trace the behavior. However, even though the new node is linked as the head node inside the function, this change doesn't seem to reflect in the actual linked list.
["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","get"]


[[],[1],[5],[8],[3],[0]]




typedef struct list {
    int val;
    struct list* next;
} MyLinkedList;


MyLinkedList* myLinkedListCreate() {
    MyLinkedList* newNode = (MyLinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(MyLinkedList));
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    newNode -> val = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int myLinkedListGet(MyLinkedList* obj, int index) {
    if(obj == NULL) return -1;
    if(index == 0) {
        return obj -> val;
    }
    MyLinkedList* temp =  obj;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp != NULL) {  
        if( i + 1 == index ) {
            return temp -> val;
        }
        i++;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    return -1;
}

void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    if(obj -> val == NULL) {
        obj -> val = val;
        printf("Assigning value to the first node\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("| current Head : %d | ", obj  -> val);
    MyLinkedList* temp = obj;
    MyLinkedList* newNode =  myLinkedListCreate();
    newNode -> val = val;
    newNode -> next = obj;
    obj = newNode; // This doesn't update the head of the real linked list
    MyLinkedList* x = obj;
    printf("new Head : %d | ", obj  -> val);
    printf("new list : ");
    while(x != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", x -> val);
        x = x -> next;
    }
     printf("\n");
    
}

void myLinkedListAddAtTail(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    MyLinkedList* newNode =  myLinkedListCreate();
    MyLinkedList* temp =  obj;
    newNode -> val = val;
    while(temp -> next != NULL) {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = newNode;
    
}

void myLinkedListAddAtIndex(MyLinkedList* obj, int index, int val) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    MyLinkedList* newNode =  myLinkedListCreate();
    MyLinkedList* temp =  obj;
    newNode -> val = val;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp != NULL) {  
        if( i + 1 == index ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    newNode -> next =  temp -> next;
    temp -> next = newNode;
    
}

void myLinkedListDeleteAtIndex(MyLinkedList* obj, int index) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    MyLinkedList* temp =  obj;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp != NULL) {  
        if( i + 1 == index ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    MyLinkedList* dummy = temp -> next;
    temp -> next = dummy -> next;
    free(dummy);
    
}

void myLinkedListFree(MyLinkedList* obj) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    MyLinkedList* temp = obj;
    while(temp != NULL) {  
        MyLinkedList* dummy = temp->next; 
        free(temp);
        temp = dummy; 
    }
}



/**
 * Your MyLinkedList struct will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyLinkedList* obj = myLinkedListCreate();
 * int param_1 = myLinkedListGet(obj, index);
 
 * myLinkedListAddAtHead(obj, val);
 
 * myLinkedListAddAtTail(obj, val);
 
 * myLinkedListAddAtIndex(obj, index, val);
 
 * myLinkedListDeleteAtIndex(obj, index);
 
 * myLinkedListFree(obj);
*/

[ there is some printf that will show u the weird behaviour ]

Create a new node with the value of the head node, make that the second node of the list, and update the value of the head.

The reason for this behaviour is described by Changing address contained by pointer using function (and about a thousand other duplicates). If you cannot change your prototypes, then Shawn offers a good solution.

@Shawn , so use the first node as dummy node to point at the new head ?
but the problem stays the same, it will not point to the new Nodes , since what happen inside the function stay inside it

No, the head node remains the head. C uses pass by value so you can't change what the caller is using as the head of the list. But you can change the values of the fields in that instance of the struct...

@Shawn alright, that sounds logic, il try it and inform you with the result

@Shawn same problem sadly, if u can go deeply to my problem and fix it i will be very grateful.
this problem seem to exist even in other questions like stacks and different data structure. u will do me huge favor

This is the pattern that Shawn is describing: https://godbolt.org/z/xzE7obhjd

You should have separate LinkedList and ListNode structs. LinkedList has a ListNode *head; pointer, and the actual data is in the chain of ListNode structs.

@Shawn Alright, I fixed it with Shawn's idea. It seems that when I tried to change the code, I left a wrong condition. I blame the 2-hour-long struggle of trying to fix this issue. I appreciate all of you. Thanks for trying to help dumb me.

" C uses pass by value so you can't change what the caller is using as the head of the list. But you can change the values of the fields in that instance of the struct. "
We can use the head as a dummy node to point to the new head.
void myLinkedListAddAtHead(MyLinkedList* obj, int val) {
    if(obj == NULL) return;
    MyLinkedList* newNode =  myLinkedListCreate();
    newNode -> val = val;
    newNode -> next = obj -> next;
    if(obj -> val == NULL) {
        obj -> val = 999;
        obj -> next = newNode;
        printf("giving first node a value \n");
        return;
    } 
    obj -> next = newNode;
}

